# AngularJS : view not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My directive with controller :

```
app.directive("photoGallery", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'part/photoGallery.html',
        controller: ["$http", function($http) {
            me = this;
            this.autoSlide = true;
            this.currentIndex = 2;
            this.autoSlide_timer;
            this.photos = [{}];

            this.Show = function(index) {
                me.currentIndex = index;
            };

            this.Next = function() {
                me.currentIndex++;
                console.log(me.currentIndex);
                if (me.currentIndex >= me.photos.length) {
                    me.currentIndex = 0;
                }
                me.Show(me.currentIndex);
            };

            this.Prev = function() {
                me.currentIndex--;
                if (me.currentIndex < 0) {
                    me.currentIndex = me.photos.length-1;
                }
                me.Show(me.currentIndex);
            };

            this.Init = function() {
                $http.get("img/slider/_data.json")
                .success(function(data) {
                    me.photos = data;
                    for(var i in me.photos) {
                        me.photos[i].index = i;
                    }
                    console.info(me.photos);
                })
                .error(function(e){
                    console.error(e);
                });
                this.autoSlide_timer = setInterval(this.Next, 1500);
            }();
        }],
        controllerAs: 'gallery'
    };
});
```

photoGallery.html :

```
<div class="GalleryContainer">{{gallery.currentIndex}}
    <div class="PhotoWrapper">
        <div ng-repeat="photo in gallery.photos" class="photo" ng-class="{active:gallery.currentIndex == photo.index}">
            <img ng-src="img/slider/{{photo.path}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, in the Next() function, I log `currentIndex`
Next() is called every 1500ms thanks to `setInterval(this.Next, 1500)` in the Init() function.
I can see in the console : 2, 3, 4, ... 10, 0, 1, 2 ...

But in the browser, `{{gallery.currentIndex}}` is never updated, it display the default value (2) (photoGallery.html line 1)

Comment: use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service instead of `setInterval`

Comment: Like @RahilWazir mentioned, use `$interval` or make a manual call to `$scope.$apply()` in your interval function (`this.Next`). `setInterval` exists outside the angular scope so you won't get any 'auto update' functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but in my controller, `this`refers to the window element... (I did `console.log(this);` at the end of Init())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use angular `$interval()` instead of JavaScript `setInterval()` function. Why ?

Because Angular needs to know when variables are updated. `$interval` make a call to `$scope.$apply()` at the end of its execution, executing a new `$digest` loop that notify the update to angular.

You can also wait the request to be successfully proceed to set you interval, to avoid errors.

```
this.Init = function() {
    $http.get("img/slider/_data.json")
    .success(function(data) {
        me.photos = data;
        for(var i in me.photos) {
            me.photos[i].index = i;
        }
        console.info(me.photos);

        me.autoSlide_timer = $interval(me.Next, 1500);
    })
    .error(function(e){
        console.error(e);
    });
}();
```

Comment: Its not `$setInterval`, its `$interval`

Comment: I guess `$interval` was one of my problems, thanks. But it seems like I have a scope problem: in controller's functions, `this` refers to the window element (top DOM element)

Comment: Have you tried to refer to window using angular `$window` instead of `this` ?

Comment: I want `this` to refer to the Model.

Comment: so when I declare `this.Next = function () /*...*/` in the controller, Next become a method of my model

Comment: Why don't you use `$scope` instead of `this`. The behaviour is a bit different from one to another. You can find more details looking to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers#answer-14168699](this answer)

Comment: because I never heard of $scope, just seen a few scripts with it. I just needed to use the `me` variable instead of this.